# Как перенести полностью всю данные с одного сервера на другой?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, миграция, migrate

Задача такая , есть сервер ubuntu который не вытягивает нагрузку. На нем лежит сайт, нужно все это перенести на другой ubuntu сервер digital oceon. Я новичок в этом и хотел бы узнать можно как-нибудь без проблем мигрировать один сервер на другой, так чтобы все корректно работало

Comment: в общем случае ответ на Ваш вопрос - никак. Для начала нужно понять, а что вообще у Вас работает (может базы нужно установить какие-то, конфиги с особых мест), потом посмотреть, что нужно скопировать. В целом, для каждого случае это достаточно индивидуальный процесс. Если Вы не верите, то просто посмотрите ещё раз в свой вопрос - Вы даже не написали, на чем сделан сайт и какую технологию он использует. А это может все перевернуть с ног на голову.

Comment: CRIU (checkpoint — restore), который вам один-в-один мигрирует данные без простоя.

Comment: вытаскиваеете блочное устройство из одного системного блока и вставляете в другой — вот вам и вся миграция (да, mac-адрес сетевой карты надо будет подправить). когда один или оба «системных блока» — виртуальные/облачные, то речь уже не о физическом блочном устройстве, а о файле с его содержимым.

Comment: Ну да, а потом у человека отваливается какой-нить летсенкрипт или перестаёт пускать сотрудников, потому что вход был через LDAP. Слепая виртуализация тоже не панацея.